# Index not used on filterd aggregate query

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I need to increase performance of the following query, which filters on column `status_classification` and aggregrates on `classification -> 'flags'` (a `jsonb` field in the form: `'{"flags": ["NO_CLASS_FOUND"]}'::jsonb`):

```sql
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ("result_materials"."classification" -> 'flags') @> '["NO_CLASS_FOUND"]' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "no_class_found",
    SUM(CASE WHEN ("result_materials"."classification" -> 'flags') @> '["RULE"]' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "rule",
    SUM(CASE WHEN ("result_materials"."classification" -> 'flags') @> '["NO_MAPPING"]' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "no_mapping"
FROM "result_materials"
WHERE "result_materials"."status_classification" = 'PROCESSED';
```

To improve performance i created an index on `status_classification`, but the query plan shows that the index was never hit, and a `Seq Scan` was performed:

```
 Aggregate  (cost=1010.15..1010.16 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=19.942..19.946 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on result_materials  (cost=0.00..869.95 rows=6231 width=202) (actual time=0.024..4.660 rows=6231 loops=1)
         Filter: ((status_classification)::text = 'PROCESSED'::text)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 5
 Planning Time: 1.212 ms
 Execution Time: 20.187 ms
```

I've tried (all sql at the end of question):

- adding an index to `status_classification`
- adding a GIN index to `classification -> 'flags'`
- adding a multi field GIN index, with `classification -> 'flags'` and `status_classification` (see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76655/postgresql-multi-column-gin-index))

The index is still not hit, and performance suffers on as the table grows.  Cardinality is low in `status_classification` field, but the entries in `classification -> 'flags'` are quite rare, so i would have thought an index very practical here.

Why is the index not used?  What am i doing wrong?

SQL to recreate my db:

```sql
create table result_materials (
  uuid int,
  status_classification varchar(30),
  classification jsonb
);

insert into result_materials(uuid, classification, status_classification)
select seq
  , case(random() *2)::int
    when 0 then '{"flags": ["NO_CLASS_FOUND"]}'::jsonb
    when 1 then '{"flags": ["RULE"]}'::jsonb
    when 2 then '{"flags": ["NO_MAPPING"]}'::jsonb end
        as dummy
  , case(random() *2)::int
    when 0 then 'NOT_PROCESSABLE'
    when 1 then 'PROCESSABLE' end
        as sta
from generate_series(1, 150000) seq;
```

Indexes attempted:

```sql
-- status_classification
create index other_testes on result_materials (status_classification);

-- classification -> 'flags'
CREATE INDEX idx_testes ON result_materials USING gin ((classification -> 'flags'));

-- multi field gin
-- REQUIRES you to run: CREATE EXTENSION btree_gin;
CREATE INDEX idx_testes ON result_materials USING gin ((classification -> 'flags'), status_classification);
```

Comment: No index will speed that up. An index is used to reduce the number of rows the query needs to process. But you WHERE condition only removes 5 of 6236 rows. So your query goes through essentially all rows of the table. And for that no index will help

Comment: Btw: the `case()` expression can also be written as: `count(*) filter (where classification @> '{"flags": ["NO_MAPPING"]}')`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the feedback, really appreciate it.  I'll try out the filter approach.  Reassuring that I'm not going crazy on the index front.

Comment: Note, the `filter()` won't speed up things - but I find that much easier to read. I think the only way to speed this up is to get a parallel seq scan

Comment: But I do find 20ms for 6236 rows **extremely** slow. But with the sample script you provided, the index **is** used, because the WHERE condition filters out half of the rows. I get 20ms runtime with the 150000 rows from your script. With only 6k rows it's less than 1ms

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name not sure if you're bothered about the points, but i found your answer really helpful, if you put an answer below i'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The query takes 20ms and only removes 5 rows of 6k, yes a scan it's a good choice.
Try adding more rows to the table, and check the cardinality of your clause.